# Enabling debug mode for denx u-boot 2015.04 on PandaBoard ES

Tags: debugging, mode, u-boot

I want to enable debug mode for denx u-boot 2015.04. However, I cant find `-DDEBUG` switch or anything similar in `config.mk`. I also tried to enable debug locally by adding `#define DEBUG` to several `[emif-common.c](https://github.com/malvira/uboot/blob/master/arch/arm/cpu/armv7/omap-common/emif-common.c)` files in `arch/arm/cpu/armv7` without success.

Comment: *"I also tried to enable debug locally by adding `#define debug 1`"* -- (1) Low-case macro name is incorrect.  Convention requires the name to be all capital letters.  (2) You would need to place the `#define DEBUG 1` before **common.h** is included.

Comment: Indeed, I changed it to upper case ``#define DEBUG`` before  common.h is included (in particular I am speaking of [emif-common.c](https://github.com/malvira/uboot/blob/master/arch/arm/cpu/armv7/omap-common/emif-common.c)). However, the ``debug()`` statements are not being put out during boot.

Comment: **have you initialized your console before the debug() is executed?** debug uses the printf() function. The code of emif-common.c looks like RAM initialization. It should be one of the first blocks to be initialized, the serial console initialization happens much later during the boot sequence.

Answer (score 5):

for me adding:

```
#ifndef DEBUG
#define DEBUG
#endif
```

in file /include/common.h worked.

Answer (score 0):

As of U-boot v2023.01, add the following:

```
 --- a/include/common.h
 +++ b/include/common.h
 @@ -12,6 +12,8 @@
  #ifndef __COMMON_H_
  #define __COMMON_H_    1
 
 +#define LOG_DEBUG
 +
  #ifndef __ASSEMBLY__       /* put C only stuff in this section */
  #include <config.h>
  #include <errno.h>
```

And then re-compile u-boot.itb with this change:

```
make CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu- u-boot.itb
```

Note: other parts such as `u-boot-tpl.bin` should not be compiled with this change, otherwise you will get:

```
aarch64-linux-gnu-ld.bfd: arch/arm/lib/reset.o: in function `do_reset':
/u-boot/arch/arm/lib/reset.c:42: undefined reference to `reset_cpu'
/u-boot/arch/arm/lib/reset.c:42:(.text.do_reset+0x24): relocation truncated to fit: R_AARCH64_CALL26 against undefined symbol `reset_cpu'
```